# Spring global scope optional path variables

Tags: spring, web, path, controller

i need to create a global scope optional path variable on my website using Spring, so the same controller could handle a requests with URL's like

```
https://website.com/something
```

and

```
https://website.com/something/5
```

And i managed to do that this way

```
@RequestMapping("/something")
public class SomethingController {

  @RequestMapping(value = {"", "/{id}) //<-- important line here
  public Model something([...]) {
    return [...]
```

But let's say that i have 50 controllers in my application and i don't wan't to modify each and every one of them. Is there any simpler way to accomplish what i need? (application-scope or controller class-scope)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extend this controllers from Base Controller that is annotated with @RequestMapping (not so flexible), or you can try design patterns like Decorator Pattern. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/decorator_pattern.htm

Comment: Im not sure if i understood you correctly, but that doesn't make much sense to me. Let's say that i would use the decorator pattern, i still would have to override every method that is annotated by `@RequestMapping`. Can you explain to me what's on your mind?

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong with suggesting decorator pattern. It won't fit in here.

Comment: Sub-classing thou seems to be a solution atm. Check this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4994

Comment: As far as i understood this solution provides prefixes, what i am talking about is a postfix.

Comment: From what I understand now is that you want something like a content manager that generates end-points of similar structure?